# React : reducer isn't updating my state when using Object.assign

Tags: reactjs, reduce

I use a reducer to update this state :

```
const [playlist, dispatch] = useReducer(jspfReducer,new playlistModel());
```

It uses my `playlistModel` class, which is just a wrapper that adds some methods to manipulate easily my data - I need it.

I want to update the state, but avoid as much possible unecessary renders.
So when calling the reducer case *UPDATE_JSPF_TRACK*; I update only the matching track of the `playlistModel` *track* array.

```
function jspfReducer(state, action){
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'UPDATE_JSPF_TRACK':
      const [index,jspf] = action.payload;

      //update only that single track.
      const newTracks = state.track.map(
        (track, i) => i === index ? new trackModel(jspf) : track
      );

      const newState = Object.assign(
        state,
        {
          track:newTracks
        }
      );

      //my object value is correctly updated here :
      console.log("NEW STATE",newState);

      return newState;

    break;
  }
};
```

The value logged in the console is correctly updated.

But in my provider, the state update is not detected:

```
export function PlaylistProvider({children}){

  const [playlist, dispatch] = useReducer(jspfReducer,new playlistModel());

  //when state updates
  useEffect(()=>{
    console.log("PLAYLIST HAS BEEN UPDATED!!!",playlist);//does not fire
  },[playlist])
```

What is wrong and how could I fix this ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to create a new object for the state changes to be detected:

```
const newState = Object.assign(
  {},
  state,
  {
    track: newTracks,
  },
);
```

or

```
const newState = { ...state, track: newTracks };
```

The way React works is it detects if the state objects have different [referential equality](https://dev.to/tylerthehaas/referential-equality-in-react-127h), which basically means that if you only modify an object's attributes, it will still be considered the same object for the purposes of rendering. To trigger state change effect you'll need to create a new object.

Comment: This "breaks" my playlistModel object, and I can't access its methods anymore.  Doing `Object.assign( new playlistModel(),state,{track: newTracks})` work, but I get a whole new object.  Which does not makes sense since it will rerender everything and not only the updated track object. :/

Comment: Not sure what kind of logic `playlistModel` has but maybe try using a simple object instead of a class? Otherwise it doesn't seem like a good idea to use a class instance in reducer, as it expects objects instead.